# Return list from async/await method

Tags: c#, list, asynchronous, async-await, task

I want to make a webservice request asynchron. I call it here:

```
List<Item> list = GetListAsync();
```

Here is the declaration of my function, which should return a list:

```
private async Task<List<Item>> GetListAsync(){
    List<Item> list = await Task.Run(() => manager.GetList());
    return list;
}
```

If I want to compile I get the following error

```
Cannot implicitely convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<Item>> to System.Collections.Generic.List<Item>
```

As I know If I use the `async` modifier the result is automatically wrapped with Task. I think this doesn't happen because I use `Task.Run`. If I remove the `Task.Run(() =>` part I get

> Cannot await System.Collections.Generic.List expression

I think I haven't fully understood the async/await methods. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type from Task<>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886559/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-from-task)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You need to correct your code to wait for the list to be downloaded:

```
List<Item> list = await GetListAsync();
```

Also, make sure that the method, where this code is located, has `async` modifier.

The reason why you get this error is that `GetListAsync` method returns a `Task<T>` which is not a completed result. As your list is downloaded asynchronously (because of `Task.Run()`) you need to "extract" the value from the task using the `await` keyword.

If you remove `Task.Run()`, you list will be downloaded synchronously and you don't need to use `Task`, `async` or `await`.

One more suggestion: you don't need to await in `GetListAsync` method if the only thing you do is just delegating the operation to a different thread, so you can shorten your code to the following:

```
private Task<List<Item>> GetListAsync(){
    return Task.Run(() => manager.GetList());
}
```

Comment: They will also need to ensure that the method calling this code is made an `async` method (if they haven't already).

Comment: What I don't get is why do I have to `await` two times?

Comment: @testing, you have to await twice because you have 2 async calls

Comment: @BenRobinson: Do I have two async calls or only one (and the second is for "extracting")?

Comment: @testing You have 2, you are awaiting the task in you `GetListAsync` method, then you are awaiting the method itself in your calling code

Answer (score 13):

In addition to @takemyoxygen's answer the convention of having a function name that ends in `Async` is that this function is truly asynchronous. I.e. it does not start a new thread and it doesn't simply call `Task.Run`. If that is all the code that is in your function, it will be better to remove it completely and simply have:

```
List<Item> list = await Task.Run(() => manager.GetList());
```

Comment: I also have a try/catch block to catch the exceptions and I'm showing a spinner. So my method name is correct than?

Comment: yes i think it should be OK, starting a new thread is not ideal but i think the guideline is more about calling a synchronous version of the function inside `Task.Run`

Answer (score 9):

Works for me:

```
List<Item> list = Task.Run(() => manager.GetList()).Result;
```

in this way it is not necessary to mark the method with async in the call.

Comment: It works, but still runs synchronously for me.

Comment: .Result treats the async method to run synchronously, so you break the async flow. Not really what you want I guess?

Answer (score 9):

you can use the following

```
private async Task<List<string>> GetItems()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(new List<string> 
    { 
      "item1", "item2", "item3" 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing all these, one can simply use ".Result" to get the result from a particular task, e.g.:

```
List<Item> list = GetListAsync().Result;
```

Which as per the definition `=>` Gets the result value of this `Task <TResult>`